# Clearcase: What is the UNL Extension on Some Directories in VOB?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

After doing a merge down into my branch some directories now have a mysterious .UNL extension and these directories seem inaccessible. In other words, I cannot check out files from them.

I am using the Clearcase remote client with Eclipse 3.7.1 on Linux RHEL 5.4. I checked the Clearcase documentation and found nothing. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but I have seen `.unl` extension to reference **unloaded** resources, so in your case, after a CCRC merge, those directories might not be visible anymore, but are somehow kept in your web view (with that extension).

The easiest way to confirm that would be to reload your CCRC view in another path, and check if those directories are still there.

Comment: Ah, I didn't deduce that .unl meant "unloaded." So does this imply that these directories have been removed from the directory structure of the VOB? Or is there another reason why a directory in my view could be unloaded? Could these be new directories that require more than a simply merge and update to load?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod If a directory is removed in one branch, and that branch is merged to another branch, the end result should be the removal of that same directory in said other branch, destination of your merge. That is because you are merging the parent directory (of the removed dir), which contains a new version, listing the sub-elements (minus the removed dir). So if your view is the view in which you did merge, you could see removed but incompletely unloaded directories as a result of that merge.

Answer (score 6):

If you have private/hijacked resources in folders which are removed (unloaded) from the VOB, such folders will be marked with an .unl extension in your view and will keep the private/hijacked resources you have had.